# Подмена данных в выводе

Tags: sql-server

Есть запрос, который при выводе выдает коды работ.

```
Select
    Id_oper, CatJob
from Work
```

И получаю на вывод:

```
ID_oper | CatJob
-------------------    
122     | s9fff7 
123     | g34fc5
124     | hgg551
```

Я думал решить эту проблему через *CASE*

```
Select
    Id_oper, 'Тип работ'=
CASE
  WHEN CatJob = 's9fff7' THEN 'Удаленные работы'
  WHEN CatJob = 'g34fc5' THEN 'Выездные работы'
  WHEN CatJob = 'hgg551' THEN 'Работы на месте'
  ELSE NULL
END
from Work
```

Но в результате выглядит, как:

```
ID_oper | Тип работ
-------------------    
122     | ?????????? ???????
123     | ????????? ???????
124     | ??????? ?? ?????
```

Есть ли какие-то аналоги *CASE*??

P.S. Расшифровки не хранятся в таблице

Comment: `WHEN CatJob = 's9fff7' THEN N'Удаленные работы'`

Comment: А можно объяснить почему это так работает?

Comment: Откройте BOL и посмотрите, что означает добавленная буква.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменяйте кодировку файла, где находится ваш запрос.
Если была Windows-1251 сделайте UTF-8,
иначе вместо UTF-8 сделайте Windows-1251.